# Remove fcn for Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++

Does this remove function for a Binary Search Tree look correct? When I try to delete a node, it runs and brings back the switch menu it's called from, but doesn't actually delete it when you reprint the tree. I'm not sure if I have a return out of place, possibly?

My question is: Does this remove statement actually remove the item passed, or does it just play around with it in a cruel fashion giving me a headache?

```
void BinarySearchTree::remove(int d)
    {
       //Locate the element
       bool found = false;
       if(isEmpty())
       {
          cout<<" This Tree is empty! "<<endl;
          return;
       }

       tree_node* curr;
       tree_node* parent;
       curr = root;

       while(curr != NULL)
       {
          if(curr->data == d)
          {
             found = true;
             break;
          }
          else
          {
             parent = curr;
             if(d>curr->data) curr = curr->right;
             else curr = curr->left;
          }
        }
        if(!found)
        {
          cout<<" Data not found! "<<endl;
          return;
        }


        // 3 cases :
        // 1. We're removing a leaf node
        // 2. We're removing a node with a single child
        // 3. we're removing a node with 2 children

        // Node with single child
            // Node with single child
if((curr->left == NULL && curr->right != NULL) || (curr->left != NULL && curr->right == NULL))
{
  if(curr->left == NULL && curr->right != NULL)
  {
     if(parent->left == curr)
     {
        parent->left = curr->right;
        delete curr;
     }
     else
     {
        parent->right = curr->right;
        delete curr;
     }
   }
   else // left child present, no right child
   {
     if(parent->left == curr)
     {
        parent->left = curr->left;
        delete curr;
     }
     else
     {
        parent->right = curr->left;
        delete curr;
     }
   }
   return;
}

        //We're looking at a leaf node
        if( curr->left == NULL && curr->right == NULL)
        {
          if(parent->left == curr)
          {
             parent->left = NULL;
          }
          else
          {
             parent->right = NULL;
          }
          delete curr;
          return;
        }


        //Node with 2 children
        // replace node with smallest value in right subtree
        if (curr->left != NULL && curr->right != NULL)
        {
           tree_node* chkr;
           chkr = curr->right;
           if((chkr->left == NULL) && (chkr->right == NULL))
           {
             curr = chkr;
             delete chkr;
             curr->right = NULL;
           }
           else // right child has children
           {
             //if the node's right child has a left child
             // Move all the way down left to locate smallest element

             if((curr->right)->left != NULL)
             {
                tree_node* lcurr;
                tree_node* lcurrp;
                lcurrp = curr->right;
                lcurr = (curr->right)->left;
                while(lcurr->left != NULL)
                {
                   lcurrp = lcurr;
                   lcurr = lcurr->left;
                }
                curr->data = lcurr->data;
                delete lcurr;
                lcurrp->left = NULL;
             }
             else
             {
                tree_node* tmp;
                tmp = curr->right;
                curr->data = tmp->data;
                curr->right = tmp->right;
                delete tmp;
             }

          }
          return;
       }

    }
```

Comment: @SaniHuttunen, why do you say so? I don't see any problem in search algorithm.

Comment: Haha... Read this on my phone and only saw the top part of the code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read ur code and I write different situations on a paper and I think in that case which the node has 2 children the code should be something like this

```
 //Node with 2 children
    if (curr->left != NULL && curr->right != NULL)
    {
        tree_node* chkr; 
        if(parent==NULL || parent->left==curr){  //if parent==NULL it means that the node that we want to delete is root
            chkr=curr->right;
            while(chkr->left!=NULL)
                chkr=chkr->left;
            if(parent!=NULL)
                parent->left=curr->right;
            else
                root=curr->right;
            chkr->left=curr->left;
            curr->left=curr->right=NULL;
            delete curr;
        }else if(parent->right==curr){
            chkr=curr->left;
            while(chkr->right!=NULL)
                chkr=chkr->right;
            parent->right=curr->left;
            chkr->right=curr->right;
            curr->left=curr->right=NULL;
            delete curr;
        }
        return;
   }
```

I didn't compile or test it but I think its gonna work,
plz let me know about it

Comment: I apparently didn't copy my code completely, I sat here for 20+ minutes trying to find that in my code and finally found that I missed the ACTUAL if part of that statement. What you have quoted is the else part that was originally thought to be missing. I've editted the main post to include the complete version.

Comment: Worked like a charm, I don't get a segmentation error anymore when I delete things. Thank you! Best answer. ;)